# Accessing variables in one instance from another class in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, class, variables, uiviewcontroller, uitextfield

The issue that I'm having is that I have several `ViewController`s, and I want to access a variable from one `ViewController` in another `ViewController`. This can probably be solved very simply (but I can't figure this out), but if I have, say, a `UITextField` called `myTextField` in `ViewController1`, how can I access `myTextField.text` from `ViewController2`?

I tried instantiating the `UIViewController` in my second class, but that doesn't work because thats just a new instantiation of the class, not the class that's already been instantiated, and therefore all the variables don't have the proper values.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by having one access the other? There may be a better way, such as a notification, a delegate, etc. If you describe what you want to accomplish, we can give you a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you are trying to do is almost certainly wrong. At the very least, it goes against the rule that you should *not* be trying to access visuals of one view from inside the other view.

You should put the data from the `UITextField` that you plan to share into your *model* class, whatever it may be, and access that data through the model, rather than trying to access `UITextField` directly.

Comment: @user1226490 It is the object that you use to keep the data in a way independent of the view. Read [this MVC](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH32) guide for more information on the model-view-controller pattern.

Answer (score 0):

simple way to access the textfield in all view controllers.

- Make a new class(subclass of NSObject)
- Make it a singleton..i.e.only one instance in the lifetime of the
  program.
- Store the text in the singleton class.
- Retrieve the singleton in other view controller and load the text..

Google singleton in objective-c to find more about it.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this, I have found, is to create a *static* method that returns the variable you are trying to access, either in a class or just as an instance variable in your first view controller.

**First View Controller**

```
+ (NSString*) returnSomestring{
    return myVariable;
    //myVariable can be replaced with textView.text or whatever you need it to be.
}
```

**Second View Controller**

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"

- (void) doSomething{
    NSString* var = [FirstViewController returnSomestring];
    //Code
}
```

Problem solved!

Comment: But my question with this idea is that wouldn't `myVariable` not be the same for every instance and therefore the class itself wouldn't know which instance to look to to return (even if there is only one allocated instance), leading to an error?